# LinkPreview - Protection against hazardous links

Tags: script, hyperlinks

### In Action

[image: LinkPreview-InAction]

### About

Links can be dangerous when clicked recklessly, especially when they are hidden by a title.

LinkPreview helps solve this problem by providing a way to view where links points to before clicking it (in posts and comments). It also color codes links by domain.

#### Download

| Version | Minified | Unminified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Version 1.0](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/LinkPreview/v1.0) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/LinkPreview/v1.0/script.min.user.js) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/LinkPreview/v1.0/script.user.js) |

#### Additional Information

| #### License | #### Suggestions/Issues |
| --- | --- |
| [MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE) | Suggestions and issues should be raised as an answer in this post |

---

Languages/libraries used: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

Comment: [*it is safe to visit*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/47912) ... for various degrees of "safe".... ;)